# How to hide wrapped components in React

Tags: css, reactjs

I need to be able to hide components that gets wrapped because it goes over the max width.

```
<div style={{width:100}}>
    <div style={{width:50}}>
        component1
    </div>
    <div style={{width:50}}>
        component2
    </div>
    <div style={{width:50}}>
        component3
    </div>
</div>

//But I actually use map to render children
<div style={{width:100}}>
    {components.map((item, index) => {
        return <div style={{width:50}}>component{index + 1}</div>)
    }}
</div>
```

as shown in the code above, the parent div is of with 100. So the last component (component3) would go over the width of the parent by 50px and will be rendered in the second line. However, I want any component that leaves the first line to be not rendered at all. How do I make sure that only component1 and component2 shows and excludes component3?

Comment: If all of the components have width 50, you could just do `components.slice(0,2).map(...)` to render the first two components.

Comment: @Tholle yes, but unfortunately that's not the case. The widths are variable

Comment: Alright. Is the 100 width of the parent variable as well?

Comment: @Tholle no the width of the parent div is not variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add up the widths of all the components in a separate variable, and render `null` for all components remaining after the total width of those already rendered exceeds 100.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    components: [{ width: 50 }, { width: 50 }, { width: 50 }]
  };
  
  render() {
    const { components } = this.state;
    let totalWidth = 0;

    return (
      <div style={{ width: 100 }}>
        {components.map((item, index) => {
          totalWidth += item.width;

          if (totalWidth > 100) {
            return null;
          }
          return (
            <div key={index} style={{ width: 50 }}>
              component{index + 1}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```